# Change font in Angular 4 Material

Tags: css, angular, material-design

How to change a font in Angular 4 Material `material.angular.io` by using the styles file in .CSS not SASS format?

The documentation provides an example for SASS:
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/typography.md.

I would like to change the font to Open Sans.

Comment: have you tried `* { font-family: 'Roboto (for example)' !important }` ?

Comment: yes, it works but also changes the font awesome/material design icon

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
*:not(.fa) {
    font-family: 'font-name' !important 
}
```

`not(.fa)` is for your font awesome icons